How to apply css gradient color to background of component similar to the one in the attached screenshot
How can we apply css gradient at one side of the background using pseudo css selectors as per the below screenshot..
enter image description here
I tried with using linear gradient css but its not the same as per the figma designs
background: linear-gradient(to top right, #0f65a5 80%, #0f65a5 50%, #0f65a5 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 100%);
Please help.. i just need that css gradient effect
How can we apply css gradient at one side of the background using pseudo css selectors as per the below screenshot..
enter image description here
I tried with using linear gradient css but its not the same as per the figma designs
background: linear-gradient(to top right, #0f65a5 80%, #0f65a5 50%, #0f65a5 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 100%);

Can anyone help here

That's not a linear gradient, it's a radial gradient - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient

This is the closest i could get. Hope this helps


background: radial-gradient(circle at 110% -10%, #ffffff, #a2c3e4, #6197ca, #2c74b1, #0f65a5, #0f65a5, #0f65a5, #0f65a5); /* made at https://learnui.design/tools/gradient-generator.html */




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
